# Azure Durable Function - load balance Activity Functions over multiple Function apps?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I've tried to build a solution in which I have multiple Function Apps deployed (in multiple Azure Regions) which all share the same Task Hub (set via [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings)) storage account. Now my idea was that since each of them should listen to new work for the Activity Functions, the load should get somewhat distributed. But thats not happening - at least with what I have tried so far. It looks like the Function App for the Activity Functions is already determined by which Orchestrator is picked. (I had to deploy the Orchestrator in together with the Activity Functions or else it wouldn't even kick off).

So my question is: Would such a scenario be possible to achieve using Durable Functions?

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "hubName": "MyTaskHub",
      "storageProvider": {
        "connectionStringName": "DurableStorage",
        "useAppLease":  false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Each durable function [related orchestrator , activity and entity functions] must have their own ```task hub```, so that they don't get into state related issues. They can share the same storage account, but not the same Task hub. see this [MS doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp#task-hub-names), especially the note above the Next steps section.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Anand Sowmithiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14973743/anand-sowmithiran). Posting your suggestion as an answer so that it will be helpful for other community members who face similar kind of issues.

> Now my idea was that since each of them should listen to new work for the Activity Functions, the load should get somewhat distributed. But thats not happening - at least with what I have tried so far. It looks like the Function App for the Activity Functions is already determined by which Orchestrator is picked.

As per the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp#task-hub-names) the Task hub should be different for each durable function which means it should have their own durable function. below is the sample Task Hub code

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "hubName": "%MyTaskHub%"
    }
  }
}
```

In addition to `host.json`, task hub names can also be configured in orchestration client binding metadata.

```
[FunctionName("HttpStart")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, methods: "post", Route = "orchestrators/{functionName}")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient(TaskHub = "%MyTaskHub%")] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    string functionName,
    ILogger log)
{
    // Function input comes from the request content.
    object eventData = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(functionName, eventData);

    log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}
```

[image]